# rspec ActionController::UrlGenerationError for create action in namespaced admin that is nested

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, actioncontroller

I'm getting this error in my controller spec for my create action

`No route matches {:action=>"create", :assessment=>{:course_id=>"1", :curriculum_id=>"1"}, :controller=>"admin/assessments"}`

Here is my controller spec:

```
it "sets the flash success" do
  set_current_admin
  course = Fabricate(:course)
  post :create, assessment: { course_id: course.id, curriculum_id: course.curriculum.id }
  expect(flash[:success]).not_to be_blank
end
```

The error occurs on the `post :create..` line.

Here is my create action for assessments:

```
def create
  @assessment = Assessment.new(assessment_params.merge!(course_id: Course.find(params[:course_id]).id))
  if @assessment.save
    flash[:success] = "You have created your assessment."
    redirect_to curriculum_course_assessment_path(@assessment.course.curriculum, @assessment.course, @assessment)
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

And, here is my routing for the assessments:

```
resources :curriculums, only: [:index, :show] do
  resources :courses, only: [:show] do
    resources :assessments, only: [:show]
    namespace :admin do
      resources :assessments, only: [:index, :new, :create, :edit, :update]
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the line from my `rake routes`...

`POST /curriculums/:curriculum_id/courses/:course_id/admin/assessments(.:format)          admin/assessments#create`

When I actually run the create action in the browser, it works fine, so I'm guessing that it's a problem with my spec's syntax.  Any advice on this would be much appreciated.  (I realize that I'm double-nesting by resources here which is not generally the best practice, but I couldn't find any other way to access the curriculums & courses params.)

Answer (score 1):

You're nesting the `course_id` and `curriculum_id` parameters inside an `assessment` hash - in the route, they are not nested.

Comment: Your spec line doesn't actually post any `assessment` data, so it would just be `post :create, course_id: foo, curriculum_id: blah, assessment: {}`. You'd only need to permit anything passed in as part of the `assessment` hash.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I added this `attrs = Fabricate.attributes_for(:assessment)` above the `post :create...` and then change that line to: `post :create, assessment: attrs, course_id: course.id, curriculum_id: course.curriculum.id`, eliminating the improper nesting problem.